# VBE IE How to click title and/or onclick?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Can someone advise how to "click" on ALPHA ?

```
</td>
<td class="center"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Edit-1');" title="ALPHA">
ALPHA
</a>
<input type="hidden" id="Org1" value="ALPHA"/>
```

I have tried multiple different methods but nothing seems to work, e.g.

```
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("ALPHA")(0).Click
```

or

```
IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("ALPHA")(0).Click
```

or

```
   .Document.all.Item("Org1").Value = "ALPHA"
   .Document.GetElementsByClassName("ALPHA")(0).Click
   .Visible = True
```

as well as

```
IE.Document.all.Item("ALPHA")(0).Click
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[title=ALPHA]").Click
```

Worth noting, we cannot see from the HTML provided whether there are parent form/frame/iframe tags to navigate. If there are, you will need to update the HTML provided to show these.

This applied a CSS selector to target the element. It looks for an element with an `a` tag that has an attribute `title` whose value is `ALPHA`.

Answer (score 1):

Look through all the anchor (i.e. A) tags and find the one with with the correct .innerText or .title.

```
for each obj in IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
    if obj.title = "ALPHA" or obj.innertext = "ALPHA" then
        obj.click
        exit for
    end if
next obj
```

You can reduce the loop by only looping through the anchor tags within that table instead of the entire document.